# Can anyone recommend a book about advanced number theory?

Tags: number-theory, book-recommendation

I read a book about number theory named: "elementary introduction to number theory" writed by Long.
Now I want a more advanced book to continue in number theory, is there anyone?

Comment: I have reopened it since the prior dupe link had mostly books on *elementary* number theory. There may be a better dupe target. There are many advanced topics so it would help to say where your interests lie.

Comment: Yeah, I want an advanced book, not elementary

Comment: For algebraic number theory, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/240075/learning-roadmap-for-algebraic-number-theory), for example. In general, see for example [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4707925/advanced-version-of-a-classical-introduction-to-modern-number-theory) or many others. Is Ireland-Rosen too elementary for you? Then you can even start with this book.

Comment: You should start by making clear what your background is in modern algebra (groups, rings, field theory), Galois theory, complex analysis, etc.

Comment: How many numbers were covered in the elementary book?